# Unity3d 2D Raycast calls sometime passing through PolygonCollider2D's points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm a Unity beginner!

The rays from my Raycast2D calls sometimes pass through points of my PolygonCollider2D and I don't know why.

Hits are marked in the following images by a small yellow horizontal line.

Expected behavior:

[image: Image: working]

A ray passing through:

[image: image: not working]

Here is my code:

(`path` being the red points of the PolygonCollider2D)

```
Debug.DrawLine(origin, new Vector3(path[i].x, path[i].y, 0), Color.yellow, 0, false);
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(path[i].y - origin.y,  path[i].x - origin.x);
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle));
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, direction);
Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, 0), new Vector3(hit.point.x - .2f, hit.point.y, 0), Color.yellow);
Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(origin.x, origin.y, 0), new Vector3(direction.x, direction.y));
```

Is it due to bad rounding?

If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try scaling your collider a little bit up? It's probably because of the floats in position of your square.

Comment: Scaling doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem originates from **floating point precision**. You cannot make exact comparisms when floats are involved. This is usually fine if you are using a normal collider that moves around a world, because the human eye cannot notice the very tiny offsets. The question is:
**Do you need to hit the very exact positions of the polygon corners?**

If no:
Cool your solution seems to work!

If yes:
You will have to increase the size of your collider by adding a *skin*. This is a technique that increases the likelyhood of a collider getting hit. If it gets hit you may need to validate the hitpoint to figure out if the hit is really a hit or not. You will still run into floating errors and you'll probably have to configure an acceptable error distance (skin width). I hope the images below illustrate my point.

[image]

In this first image is the example of your raycast not hitting the collider.
Note that the dimensions in my images are off to illustrate my point.

[image]

Here we are **still using only 1 collider** but we have increased its size.

Keep in mind that floating point arithmentic cannot be exact. If you want to do exact math you will need to somehow work around the issue. In this case the solution would be to add a *skin*. This might not be very easy for you because you are using polygon colliders though.

Comment: Instead of implementing the skin which can be complicated as you said I decided to offset the points slightly: `worldPath[i] = new Vector2(path[i].x * .99f + this.transform.position.x, path[i].y * .99f + this.transform.position.y);` It seems to work. What do you think about this?

Comment: Sure, you either have to size up your collider or cast a different ray. It should work :) Note however, that your current solution has a dynamic correction. The bigger the collider, the bigger your correction. The correction will always be 1 % of the point's location. If that proves to cause a problem you will need to implement a static correction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. I will accept your solution.

Comment: Ooh, I'd really want to fiddle with the red line in that image so it has some jaggies showing the floating point error. One of the jags making it avoid the corner would be awesome. Something like... https://s12.postimg.org/dk5pe30gt/float.png

Comment: @Draco18s Great idea! Looks very good. Didn't thought about it :)